# Casting typedef'd numeric type to size_t catching overflows

Tags: c, casting

I have an unknown typedef'd numeric type. I'd like to cast it to a `size_t` if possible (read: if it fits within the range of a `size_t`), otherwise falling through to some error handling code.

Is there a portable way to do so?

Effectively what I'd like to do is:

```
some_int_type val = <blah>;
if (val < 0 || val > SIZE_MAX) {
    // handle error
} else {
    return (size_t) val;
}
```

However, this doesn't work, as val may be signed.

My second thought would be to do this:

```
if (val < 0 || (unsigned_some_int_type) val > SIZE_MAX) {
    // handle error
} else {
    return (size_t) val;
}
```

This would work (I think) - except that I don't have the unsigned version of `some_int_type`. I could cast them both to `some_int_type`, except that that would not work properly if `some_int_type` is smaller than `size_t` (and wouldn't work properly if `some_int_type` is signed, either, now that I think about it). I could cast them both to `uintmax_t` - except that some compilers actually have integer types larger than `uintmax_t`. (Notably, `__[u]int128`).

So how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you think the first version does not work?

Comment: How can a type be "unknown"?

Comment: @EugeneSh. When it's in an external library that it's built with at compile time.

Comment: I'm inexperienced with it myself, but this seems like a situation for <type_traits> to me.

Comment: @TLW If it is known to compiler - it is known.

Comment: @TLW, if the typedef in question is accessible to your code *at all*, then that's because its declaration is visible, presumably somewhere in one of the header files provided with the library.  One approach, therefore, is to find the relevant declaration to sort out the underlying type.

Comment: As @Olaf inquired: In the first case, if val is signed, you would correctly detect this and take the error path.

Comment: @Olaf "error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions"

Comment: @JohnBollinger - That defeats the purpose of the typedef. Not to mention even if I were to take that approach it wouldn't work as said typedef is defined to different types on different versions of said library.

Comment: @TLW C is a *statically* typed language. A type of *anything* is known at the compile time. When you are using a type, it is assumed that you know how to use it and which operations are permitted. Or, if it is opaque, you are provided some API along with it. Otherwise you are not supposed to touch it.

Comment: If one version of the library uses an unsigned typedef and another version uses a signed typedef, then that's a good indication that you shouldn't be using that library.

Comment: @TLW "comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions" should be a warning.  Was it truly a warning? or do you have an option that is treating warnings as errors?

Comment: @TLW: That would be subject to integer promotions. While the warning normally is helpful, there are exceptions. A common way is to temporarily disable that warning for this specific line or typecast both to `uintmax_t` for the second part. Anyway, if you have to convert it to `size_t`, it might be a good idea to actually `typedef size_t` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's original code should be fine

```
some_int_type val = <blah>;
if (val < 0 || val > SIZE_MAX) {
    // handle error
} else {
    return (size_t) val;
}
```

[OP commented to @Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208384/casting-typedefd-numeric-type-to-size-t-catching-overflows/38211012#comment63841232_38208384) "error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions".  Either OP truly saw a *warning* or has warnings being treated as errors.  IAC, it is not a error per C.

If OP is unable to ignore the warning/error, then *gently* convert to `size_t` only as needed.  If the unknown type is wider than `size_t`, multiplying it by `(size_t)1` will not change type and the compare warning should not occur.  IAC, the value of `val` will not change.

```
#include <stdint.h>
if (val < 0 || (size_t)1 * val > SIZE_MAX) {
```

Let the compiler optimize it.  Only lesser compilers, could use `(size_t)0 + val`.

---

Further: the message "comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions" comes up only in **select** signed integer and unsigned integer compares.  It does not come up when the unsigned integer fits in the range of the signed integer type as there would be no problem converting the unsigned integer type to the wider signed integer type.

Comment: That's a neat way of doing a cast. And yes, Werror is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Worry about the lack of an unsigned version by pulling it inside the test for positive

```
if (val >= 0 )
{
    if (val <=  SIZE_MAX)
    {
        return (size_t) val;
    }
}

// Handle error
return 0;
```

Comment: This is not semantically different from the OP's first code.  The OP's is fine, and therefore so is this, but there is no reason to prefer this to the OP's.

Comment: Purely speculative, but deep linters, like coverity might not warn on lack of signed if code is inside a block that asserts that values are positive

Comment: The first line will generate a warning if `val` is an `unsigned` type, since the condition is always true in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure why `coverity` would care about something similar to a conditional compile technique (condition always true).  It would seem more the job of for the compiler's optimizer.  But if your test showed that, OK

Answer (score 0):

After checking the negative case, check if the size of the type in question is bigger than a `size_t`.  If so, cast `SIZE_MAX` to type `some_int_type` and do the comparison.  If not, the value can't be larger than `SIZE_MAX`.

```
if (val < 0) {
    // handle error
} else if ((sizeof(some_int_type) > sizeof(size_t)) && (val > (some_int_type)SIZE_MAX)) {
    // handle error
} else {
    return (size_t) val;
}
```